# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is not able to find a HTML form

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, forms

In a `UIWebView` I loaded an HTML form using `loadHTMLString`. `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is not able to find the HTML form in this `UIWebView`.

I have tried the following :

```
NSString *javascriptToGetTheForm = @"document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];";
NSString *theForm = [self.webPortalWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javascriptToGetTheForm];
```

Tried without ';'

```
NSString *javascriptToGetTheForm = @"document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]";
NSString *theForm = [self.webPortalWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javascriptToGetTheForm];
```

Both times I printed the value of theForm is using GDB

> (lldb) p theForm
>   (__NSCFConstantString *) $0 = 0x377a6004 @""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *javascriptToGetTheForm = @"document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]";
```

Above line fetches DOM object and not NSString. So now if you do stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString on below string

```
@"document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()"
```

the form gets submitted.

Below line gets the source code of the form in NSString

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')
```